# Xperia phone does not enter doInbackground() of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sdk-2.3

I'm testing out a library file I've created (a jar file) . And inside this library, I use an asynctask. I mainly test it with a motorola Atrix 2.3.6.  However i've also tested it with a samsung nexus S and a Galaxy tablet, and everything works perfectly.

However, I've tried it on a Xperia 2.3.7 and when I'm debugging I get into the PreExecute() of my Asynctask, but it never even enters the doInBackground().  HOWEVER, I have a second asynctask that is inside of the main activity. (Not from a jar). And that seams to work ok on the Xperia.

There are no error logs, as there are no errors reported, it just simply never gets there.

Something to note, is that this is a rooted phone that has some parts swapped in from another phone. Which might have something to do with it.. But I don't see how.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the second `AsyncTask` loops? As in never ending loop? If so, you might have a problem - in Android > 3.0 all AyncTask run in the same thread, one after another.
This behaviour might be implemented in Xperia as well.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Tomasz. I've figured out what was going on. But that is a good point to mention about Android 3.0 devices. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured out the issue. For some reason the code was just never able to break point.. No idea why. However the code was still being executed, so I was able to move forward. The phone actually had some further compatibility issues which caused the other problems I was seeing which prompted my question.